# JQuery :I want to focus back to a textbox on its blur event

Tags: jquery

I am using a form which has many textboxes to validate.I am using bValidator Plugin available.What I want is that when the validation is wrong the focus should remain on that textbox .it should not move to the next text box.

The code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $($("form:first :input")[0]).focus();
            var options = {

            errorClass:"txtbox-error",
            validClass:"txtbox-success",
            validateOn:"focusout",
            onAfterElementValidation: function(element){
                var elt=element.attr('id'); 

                $("#" + elt).focus();

                }


                };


        $('#fValidation').bValidator(options);
         $('#name').focus(function(){

         });
    });
```

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a function for the `blur` event. I've knocked up an example (which can also be seen at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4fu7/))

```
<input type="text" id="text1"></input>
<input type="text" id="text2"></input>
....
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text1").blur(function(evnt){
        if ($(this).text != "1"){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Must be 1");
           $(this).focus(); 
        }
    });
});
```

However, be wary of this! Consider the usability perspecive. What if the user wants to navigate away to somewhere completely different? (I.e. away from your website) If they have focused on your text box, then they will be forced to enter a valid value even though they don't want to!